# Java Basepeer - Get ID of The Last Inserted Record

Tags: java

In php, to get the ID of the last inserted record we do this :

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

I'm trying to achieve this through [doInsert(Criteria)](https://db.apache.org/torque/torque-3.3/releases/torque-3.3/runtime/apidocs/org/apache/torque/util/BasePeer.html#doInsert(org.apache.torque.util.Criteria)) .

As I understand from their documentation, I did this :

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.add(TABLE_NAME,"column1", val1);
criteria.add(TABLE_NAME,"column2", val2);
try {
    ObjectKey object = BasePeer.doInsert(criteria);
} catch (TorqueException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

but the doInsert(Criteria) ended up with a NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you add stack trace for the NPE?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.torque.util.BasePeer.doInsert(BasePeer.java:503)
 at org.apache.torque.util.BasePeer.doInsert(BasePeer.java:437)
 at com.lamsa.zoho.ZohoDAO.save(ZohoDAO.java:31)
 at com.lamsa.zoho.Zoho.execute(Zoho.java:610)
 at com.lamsa.zoho.Zoho.access$0(Zoho.java:568)
 at com.lamsa.zoho.Zoho$1.run(Zoho.java:188)
@djm.im

Answer (score 0):

Try this to retrieve the last inserted record in sql_database using Java

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select last_insert_id() as last_id from schedule");
lastid = rs.getString("last_id");
```

Comment: I want to do this using Basepeer not st.executeQuery() because I don't have a statement or a resultset.

here is a link to [Basepeer](https://db.apache.org/torque/torque-3.3/releases/torque-3.3/runtime/apidocs/org/apache/torque/util/BasePeer.html)